# Slash issue with json_encode. Why and how to solve it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, json

Why outputting this date `("2011/7/11")` with `json_encode` displays `("2011\/7\/11")`?

How can I convert `"2011\/7\/11"` to `"2011/7/11"`?

```
$data_go = '2011/7/11';
$ddmmyyy='([1-9][\d]{3})[- \/.]([0-1][\d])[- \/.]([0-3][\d])';
            if(preg_match("/$ddmmyyy$/", $data_go)) {
            $year = substr($data_go,0,4);
            $month = substr($data_go,5,2);
            $day = substr($data_go,8,2);
            $j2g = $this->convert_date->JalaliToGregorian($year, $month, $day);
             $ok = $j2g[0]."/".$j2g[1]."/".$j2g[2];
            }else {
              return FALSE;
            }
echo json_encode($ok); // output "2011\/7\/11"
```

Comment: `"2011\/7\/11"` is valid JSON string... all `/` must be escaped by prefixing with \

Comment: @Salman A: what do i do?how is it?

Comment: what do you plan to do with the output? why not `echo $ok;`?

Comment: 2011/7/11-> removed backslash. why json_encode not can removed backslash?

Comment: Having a backslash there **is valid JSON**.

Comment: How is this actually causing a problem? Any JSON parser would see `/` and `\/` as identical.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In PHP 5.4, you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`:

```
echo json_encode("2011/7/11", JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Otherwise, you have to do some trivial post-processing

```
str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode("2011/7/11"));
```

Note that `\/` is a valid way to represent `/` in JSON.

Comment: It is essentially a bug in PHP that json_encode requires this flag to output typical json.  The json spec does not require slashes to be escaped. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49366

Comment: PHP uses historical logic that caused magic_quotes_gpc to appear in the past. Namely, it tries to do half-assed encoding to avoid most simple attacks due to missing encoding. In this case, the reason is to allow web dev to code `"<script>".json_encode($whatever)."</script>"` where $whatever may include literal `"</script>"` somewhere. Optional encoding of slashes will convert `"</script>"` into `"<\/script>"` which avoids the problem of interpreting rest of the string as raw HTML.

Answer (score -10):

```
$data_go = str_replace('\'','', $data_go);
```

it will remove all forwards slashes and will give you desired result..

Comment: this have error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE ...

Comment: there's a missing single quote after the escaped one. That line should be `$data_go = str_replace('\'','', $data_go);`

Comment: This code is simply relacing single quotes with nothing. Artefacto got it right.