# Having trouble while trying to send URL via JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am working on web services of Android application in PHP. I am trying to send URL with other data in JSON. But the data sent by URL shows unwanted slashes (//) in the URL.

Here is the code I am using:

```
if(isset($_POST['category_id'])):

        $result=$db->sub_category($_POST['category_id']);
        if($result):
        $msg="Success";
        $arr = array();
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)):
            $arr['response'][] = array('category' => $row['category'], 'image' => "http://intelmobizsolution.com/Iphone/upload/iphone/".$row['image'], 'msg'=>$msg,'status'=>true); 
        endwhile;
        $abc=json_encode($arr);
        echo json_encode($arr);
        endif;


endif;
```

But the result shows like this:

```
{"response":[{"category":"Administrative Support2","image":"http:\/\/intelmobizsolution.com\/Iphone\/upload\/iphone\/27792582102banner_02.jpg","msg":"Success","status":true}]}
```

How can I send a URL with JSON in the format I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach is to **accept the slashes**. They do absolutely not harm. It is perfectly acceptable to have them escaped in JSON strings.

If you really want to get rid of them, then you can use:

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

… but if your data ever includes the string `</script>` and you output the JSON into some JavaScript in an HTML document, then you'll break your script.

Comment: it is giving me the following error:
json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 
but, it works fine with str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode("2011/7/11"));
from the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743554/problem-slash-with-json-encode-why-and-how-solve-it

Comment: If `json_encode` expects exactly 1 parameter then you are using an out of date version of PHP.

Comment: hmm.. yes sir you are absolutely right,, and thanks a lot for the solution.... :)

Answer (score 3):

In PHP > 5.4 you can use

`json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php