# PHP cURL malformed URL issue

Tags: php, curl

This is the output from curl_getinfo($process); Why is it inserting \ characters. When I go to make the request I get errors about the URL not existing. Well duh, those characters don't exist... and it's not a valid URL.

```
https:\/\/test-test.xxx.com\/wapi\/v2.6.1\/network
```

Why isn't it just:

```
https://test-test.xxx.com/wapi/v2.6.1/network
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($process);
error_log( json_encode( curl_getinfo($process) ) );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slash issue with json\_encode. Why and how to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743554/slash-issue-with-json-encode-why-and-how-to-solve-it)

Comment: I think the password on the account expired that I'm using for the API. Instead of throwing an error that the account expired it just bombs out.